# Authorization Code disappearing from Lightning URL parameters

Tags: lightning-web-components, authorization

I am trying to integrate one salesforce org with another org using OAuth Web server flow. I provided callback url as the lightning app page. Within the LWC component on the page, I have code to extract authorization code that target Salesforce org returns. I see that code is being received in the lightning app page(using URL redirect extension) after user authorizes the app. But as soon as the page loads, code is disappearing. I believe it is because Salesforce is not appending default namespace c to code attribute(c__code).(due to critical update - https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm) How do I extract authorization code?

Comment: i'll give a vf page as callback url and use it as intermediary page to modify url parameter to add default namespace and share how it goes.

Comment: using vf page as intermediary page is working but still looking for a more cleaner solution.

Comment: Can u pls let us know if u got any solution for this without using vf page?

Comment: Any one found any solution for this ?